# wireless internet connection does not work, wired connection has internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, broadband

I am having iball 150M ADSL router I have been using this router for past one year without any problems.

Recently I noticed I can browse the internet via this router using a lan wire.

When connected wirelessly the router is unable to connect to internet.
When I boot any computer or bring a mobile phone etc those devices can connect to this router via wifi but 
can not access internet.

Where as in same situation if I put my lan wire then I can connect to internet.
What should I check or do? Following is router
[http://www.flipkart.com/iball-150m-wireless-n-adsl2-router/p/itmd375x5yfzbsgb]Iball 150M Wireless-N ADSL2+ Router - iBall: Flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com/iball-150m-wireless-n-adsl2-router/p/itmd375x5yfzbsgb%5DIball%20150M%20Wireless-N%20ADSL2+%20Router%20-%20iBall:%20Flipkart.com)

Following is ping reply when connected with LAN wire in RJ-45

```
nerd@ubuntu:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.236.178) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.236.178): icmp_req=1
ttl=55 time=378 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.236.178): icmp_req=2
ttl=55 time=381 ms
64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f18.1e100.net (74.125.236.178): icmp_req=3
ttl=55 time=382 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 3 received, 25% packet loss, time 3000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 378.491/380.703/382.488/1.806 ms
```

Following is when going wireless

```
nerd@ubuntu:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

from a wireless connection

```
nerd@ubuntu:~$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=10 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=13 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=16 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=19 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.5 icmp_seq=22 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
29 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 28149ms
```

From a wired connection

```
nerd@ubuntu:~$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=254 time=0.495 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=254 time=0.572 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=254 time=0.626 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=254 time=0.480 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=5 ttl=254 time=0.506 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_req=6 ttl=254 time=0.464 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.464/0.523/0.626/0.064 ms
```

Scanning the wifi network

```
nerd@ubuntu:~$ sudo iwlist eth1 scanning | egrep 'Cell
|Encryption|Quality|Last beacon|ESSID'
Cell 01 - Address: Lolz:Lolz:Lolz:Lolz:Lolz
ESSID:"abit2"
Quality:5/5 Signal level:-40 dBm Noise level:-92 dBm
Encryption key:on

 Device: eth1 [abit2] --------------------------------------------------------
Type: 802.11 WiFi
Driver: wl
State: connected
Default: no
HW Address:

Capabilities:
Speed: 54 Mb/s

Wireless Properties
WEP Encryption: yes
WPA Encryption: yes
WPA2 Encryption: yes

Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
*abit2: Infra, sssssss, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 0 Mb/s, Strength 100 WPA2

IPv4 Settings:
Address: 192.168.1.5
Prefix: 24 (255.255.255.0)
Gateway: 192.168.1.1

DNS: 192.168.1.1
```

So that means at least I am connected to 192.168.1.1 via wireless my
IP is 192.168.1.5 but the internet is not working,
the internet is there in router I can access internet via a LAN wire under same conditions.But not using the wireless connections.

Comment: I would think this has something to do with DNS. Could you provide some DNS diagnostics?

Comment: I seem to have figured out the problem, the problem is being caused by the way Ubuntu handles encryption, in Windows I changed the settings to TKIP it is easily able to get to internet where as in Ubuntu 12.04 I see only WPA& WPA2 Personal Ubuntu probably is not able to detect type of encryption at router, at router it is set to WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK

Comment: Exellent. Thank you for sharing your findings, baffled me yesterday this.

Answer (score 0):

Try pinging some public IP -- example google DNS server 8.8.8.8. If this goes through it is definitely a DNS issue somewhere.

Comment: This is not an answer, posts like this should be saved for the comments section.